# jQuery performance when appending data to the page

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a snippet of code that loops and appends data to a html table

```
for(var i = 0; i < iRowCount; i++)
    {
        var sTempVal = aAdditionValues[i];
        var iStartColumn = 0;
        var iIndex = 0;

        var aTempVal = sTempVal.split("");          
        aTempVal.reverse();
        for(var r = iColCount - 1; r > 0; r--)
        {
            $("#additionTable tr:eq("+i+") td:eq("+r+")").append(aTempVal[iIndex]);             
            iIndex++;
        }
        iStartColumn = 0;
        iIndex = 0;
    }
```

the array `aAdditionValues[i];` is just an array of numbers.

Is there any performance enhancements that I could implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you manipulate certain cells of an existing table there is not much room for improvements. I'd suggest caching the jquery selector at least:

```
var $table = $('#additionTable'); // outside the loop ofc
$("tr:eq("+i+") td:eq("+r+")", $table).append(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are adding something to the DOM every loop, which is highly inefficient. First create the object to be inserted in JavaScript before adding it to the DOM, inserting it in one event. This will minimize the calculations needed to repaint the document.

Answer (score 1):

Small improvements:
You can at least get rid of the `aTempVal.reverse();` and just start looping from the end.

Also remove `iStartColumn` you are not changing the value.

Answer (score 1):

Every time when you append something to DOM you rebuild it and it take a lot of resources. It will be faster create table by `createElement("table")` fill it and only after that to do one `append`.

Comment: or, of course, if it's possible to create a part of table and than insert it by one `append` it will be even better =)